# Доступ к памяти из кучи после её освобождения

Tags: c++, память

Почему не ловлю ошибку сегментирования в этом случае?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int* ptr = new int(47);

    std::cout << ptr << " " << *ptr << std::endl;

    /* 
      Память выделенная в heap'e должна вернуться системе.
      Или она будет доступна программе до окончания области
      видимости указателя ?
    */
    delete ptr;

    *ptr = 74;

    std::cout << ptr << " " << *ptr << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Вот знаменитый ответ по теме: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Разименовывание невалидного указателя приводит к неопределенному поведению - так на C++ писать нельзя.

"Неопределенное поведение" вовсе не означает, что программа выпадет с ошибкой. В таком состоянии, программа может делать *все что угодно*, в том числе и работать так, как этого хочет программист.

Допускать неопределенное поведение в программе запрещено.

Comment: Фразу "в том числе, и работать в соответствии со своей спецификацией" я бы заменил на какую-то другую конструкцию, потому что спецификация предполагает неопределённое поведение, а тут скорее подразумевается "то, что имел в виду программист" или "игнорируя проблему".

Comment: @Discord Под "спецификацией" здесь и понимается - "то, что хочет от программы программист".

Comment: Значение я понимаю, но эта формулировка создаёт путаницу.

Comment: Как бы это сформулировать... Слишком по-военному получается - "нельзя, потому что так сказано". Но, вообще говоря, при обсуждении этого вопроса комитетом явно рассматривалось, **почему** решено именно так. Мне кажется, пояснения "почему" не мешают. Не стоит делать из системы черный ящик и запрещать что-то просто потому, что так положено :)

Answer (score 7):

Как *обычно* работает менеджер памяти? Изначально есть большой кусок памяти, с которым можно работать, и который помечен, как свободный. Менеджер при запросе может, например, выделить кусок памяти и сохранить у себя в своем внутреннем списке пометку - вот эта память выделена, ее не трогать... (на самом деле это отдельная и очень серьезная тема, но для пояснения хватит и такого представления). Освобождается блок - менеждер делает соответствующую отметку у себя. Скорее всего, перед блоком будет находиться небольшой блок со служебной информацией - о занятости, размере занятого блока и т.п.

Что происходит при освобождении с самой памятью? Ничего. Она просто помечается как свободная. Меняется только информация в служебных полях.

Поэтому вы можете записать туда информацию. Или считать.

Но даже если вы делаете это прямо после освобождения, без промежуточных действий - уже никто не может вам гарантировать корректности этого действия: вдруг тот же менеджер именно на это место запишет свою служебную информацию, так что вы просто ее испортите? Или другой поток успеет захватить эту память себе? Что именно произойдет, не знает никто, так что о таких ситуациях так и говорится - "неопределенное поведение".

Словом, получить аварийное завершение программы в такой ситуации - это скорее везение. Невезение - **не** получить никакой ошибки, но запороть память, и потом, через 15 минут работы программы получить неприятности - например, совершенно неверное значение переменной, которое вы вроде бы сохраняли как совсем другое. И потом долго - **очень** долго искать ошибку, которая расположена совсем в другом месте программы, да еще и не воспроизводится стопроцентно при каждом запуске...

Comment: Обычно менеджеры памяти работают совсем не так :)

Comment: @Harry - замена знаний на домыслы в программировании приводит, в дальнейшем, к "мистическому" отношению к машине и работающим в ней программам. Вы либо знаете, как что-то работает - читали исходник, посещали течтолк, читали книгу, либо относитесь к этой сущности, как к черному ящику.

Comment: @ixSci "Совсем"? По-моему, абстракция "менеджер памяти где-то как-то хранит информацию о том, какая память выделена/свободна, и освобождение блока памяти часто не приводит к недоступности блока или уничтожению данных в нём" вполне себе имеет право на существование. Описание деталей правда несколько наизнанку, ну да какая разница-то...

Comment: @gbg Не могу придумать ситуацию, когда расхождение описанного с реальностью может привести к неверному пониманию происходящего. Восприятие менеджера памяти как чёрного ящика всё ещё остаётся, но не возникает реакции "WTF" на описанное в вопросе — уже прогресс.

Comment: @Discord учитывая, что вы также опубликовали ответ, состоящий из домыслов, я не удивлен. У вас там какая-то "операционная система", какие-то "блоки". Программа на C++ может работать на голом железе, где никакой операционной системы нет; может работать с памятью вроде XMS, где доступ происходит через форточку размером 64 килобайта, и так далее. Сочинять мифы и легенды о том, что же происходит в время UB - пустая трата времени. Ответ на вопрос автора - "вы сотворили UB". На то оно и UB, что описать, что происходит без домыслов - невозможно.

Comment: @gbg, UB это замечательно, но понимание того как это происходит, хотя бы на какой-то ОС, позволяет понять, почему же не происходит падения; кроме того, это позволяет лучше ориентироваться в системе. Пуризм это хорошо, иногда, но это не тот случай. Подобные примеры(что в вопросе) и подобные ответы(несомненно куда более глубокие и полные) находятся в книгах, которые пишутся различными именитыми людьми. Я к чему это — да, я согласен, что нужно понимать, что программа написана неправильно, но нет ничего плохого в том, что автору объяснили, что _может_ происходить под капотом.

Comment: @Discord, мне не нравится «большой кусок памяти». Есть две базовые реализации: список блоков фиксированного размера, и хэш-таблица блоков различных размеров. Есть куча других реализаций, но если говорить про «обычно», то именно про это.

Comment: @gbg Никого не интересуют экзотические оси (здесь: "никого" — меньше 1 процента программистов (здесь: "процент" — взятое из головы число)).

Comment: @Discord красиво вы по разработчикам встроенных систем прошлись, ничего не скажешь.

Comment: @gbg Они статистическая погрешность.

Answer (score 5):

Когда вы освобождаете блок памяти, а потом работаете с ним, может произойти что угодно. "Что угодно" включает:

- Блок памяти мог был помещён менеджером памяти в список свободных. Данные в самом блоке при этом обычно не затираются, поэтому при доступе к "удалённой" памяти она всё ещё будет содержать нужную вам информацию.
- Если вы используете отладочный режим или какой-нибудь защитник от ошибок, то менеджер памяти мог намеренно затереть данные в освобождённом блоке. В результате при чтении данных вы заведомо получите мусор.
- Освобождённый блок памяти или его часть могли быть отданы менеджером памяти какому-то другому куску вашего кода. Содержимое, соответственно, могло быть перезаписано этим другим куском кода. Данные вы прочитаете, но интерпретируете неверно, поэтому для вас это будет мусором.
- Менеджер памяти мог решить отдать ненужную страницу памяти вместе с вашим блоком операционной системе. При попытке доступа к "дырке" вы получите ошибку доступа, и ваш процесс рухнет.

Нюанс в том, что операционная система работает с большими блоками памяти, а вашей программе хочется мелкие, поэтому менеджер памяти будет запрашивать большие куски у оси, а потом разбираться с раздачей мелких кусков в больших кусках самостоятельно. Когда вы освобождаете мелкий кусок, совсем не факт, что менеджер памяти будет освобождать большой кусок, который содержит ваш мелкий.